# How to get time in between start and end time in php?

Tags: php, time

```
$time1 = new DateTime($post->clock_in);
$time2 = new DateTime($post->clock_out);
$interval = date_diff($time1,$time2);
$difference = $interval->format('%H:%I');
```

In this above code I want to get exact time between two different time. Now, What happen if `$time1 = '10:00'` and `$time2 = '05:00'` then difference between these two time is `07:00` but it show `05:00`. I don't know why? So, How can I get the exact timing between two timing? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: "_then difference between these two time is 07:00_" How so? (The _difference_ is 5 hours)

Comment: @kerbh0lz it seems time1 is 10AM and time2 is 5PM

Comment: exactly @maniksidana

Comment: Then OP should tell his script to take this into consideration. Or use `17:00` as end time

Comment: @kerbh0lz fair enough. that should resolve the issue

Comment: So what exaclty are `$post->clock_in` and `$post->clock_out` then?

Comment: @CBroe these are dynamic value

Comment: Well, duh. I meant what values they have _in this specific instance_.

Comment: What is the value of `$post->clock-out` ?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$d1=new DateTime("2012-07-08 11:14:15.638276");
$d2=new DateTime("2012-07-08 11:14:15.889342");
$diff=$d2->diff($d1);
print_r( $diff ) ;
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Comment: How does that differ? Using `10:00` and `05:00` will also return a 5 hour difference

Comment: it's right - difference 5 hours, use correct format of time) see http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4b5492e063c3d487b8be82b00a0708b9ffda5b57